# Python-Django How to use django-ajax-uploader in admin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, upload, django-imagekit

I have searched a lot on this with no luck to find an exact answer.

I want to use django-ajax-uploader inside admin's edit form.

I have a model with an image field. In admin side i am excluding that field and inserting the ajax-uploader into the admin form via jquery. It is because once the image uploaded via ajax-uploader a crop resize viewport is becoming active that updates crop and resize numeric fields... will be used with imagekit.

Now when submitting the form, django can not reach the file object.

Is there anybody having an opinion on that?

Comment: What means "Django can not reach the file object"? It is not present in request.FILES ? If so - check if the <form> has enctype=multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

I feel, that you use standard form submit & server-side handler. This doesn't work for ajax uploader

According to https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-ajax-uploader#signals, you have to handle special signal to store data from ajax uploader.